# Wifi not working on 14.04 notebook

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, acer, ethernet

I have this Acer Aspire V5 notebook, which had problems with wifi before in 13.10 and i had to use the ethernet. sometimes it randomly started working but most of the time it wouldn't. So then i updated and wifi still doesn't work, no matter what i try.

I tried unplugging the cable, replugging it while connecting to wifi and some other combos but it just doesn't connect. it shows that blank wifi symbol everytime. :( please i'm looking for help anything appreciated. oh btw ethernet cable works fine :/ but it's annoying to switch it between my desktop and laptop everyime :P

Comment: user272460 perhaps this will help your issue

http://askubuntu.com/a/496977/299981

Comment: I had that problem before and i solved it after following this instruction.
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=208434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if there is a driver available for your chipset.  Go to software (software sources) and the tab all the way to the right should say something like "additional Drivers".  See if anything is available.  Otherwise, give use the output of 'lspci' so we can see what chipset you're using and try to figure things out from there.

Comment: it searches for some drivers but then there's nothing and i can't put the lspci here since it's too long so here's a link: http://pastebin.com/LHM8ZuDc

Comment: This is the relevant part that we're looking for:

03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

You'll want to look online and see if there's any specific instruction for getting that wireless card up and running under Ubuntu.  I'm at work now so I'll have to dissect further when I get home.  Good luck!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I did what one thread suggested, rebooted and now i'm finally mobile with my notebook! love you guys.... if anyone wondering http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044 this thread, i combined a few suggestions together and now i can finally disconnect from that annoying ethernet cable! <3